# Retrieve data from HTML form to server file

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am working on the Stripe payment API and I have a form to collect data that is written in HTML and would like to retrieve the collected data to another javascript file (server.js). I have tried changing the `${AMOUNT}` to `req.body.amount` but seems that is not the case. Is it actually possible to retrieve the data via the `form` method? Or it is only be done in the `fetch` method?

**HTML:**

```
<form action="/create-checkout-session" method="POST" id="create-checkout-session">
  <div className="description">
    <span>Price:</span> 
    <input type="number" className="field" id="amount" name="amount" min="500"/>
    <button type="submit" id="checkout">
      Checkout
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Javascript (server.js):**

```
app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
line_items: [
  {
    price_data: {
      currency: 'hkd',
      product_data: {
        name: "Test",
      },
      unit_amount: ${AMOUNT},
    },
    quantity: 1,
  },
],
mode: 'payment',
success_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}?success=true`,
cancel_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}?canceled=true`,});
res.redirect(303, session.url);
});
app.listen(4242, () => console.log('Running on port 4242'));
```

Comment: When I try using req.body.amount, it throws out an error:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'amount')
I have no idea why this happened since the value is already be input...

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by adding `express.urlencoded` in the server.js, which looks like this:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```